# Operations with ideals: sum and product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Operations at ideals.

The sum is defined as $$I_1 + I_2 + \dots + I_m =\{a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_m\mid a_i \in I_i\}.$$ It can be proven that $$I_1 + I_2 + \dots + I_m \trianglelefteq R$$ and each $$I_i\subseteq I_1 + I_2 + \dots + I_m. $$

The product is defined as $$I_1 \cdot I_2 \cdot \dots \cdot I_m  =\{\text{finite sum of products } a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot \dots \cdot a_m \mid a_i \in I_i\}.$$ It can be proven that $$I_1 \cdot I_2 \cdot \dots \cdot I_m \trianglelefteq R$$ $$I_1 \cdot I_2 \cdot \dots \cdot I_m \subset I_i.$$

Could you explain to me why the subsets hold??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_i\in I_i$, $a_i=0+\cdots+a_i+\cdots+0\in I_1+\cdots+I_m$.

If $a_i\in I_i$ for each $1\le i\le m$, then $a_1\cdot\ldots\cdot a_m\in I_1\cap\cdots\cap I_m$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $(I_1+\cdots+ I_m)\le R$ or $(I_1\cdot\ldots\cdot I_m)\le R$.

Comment: Why does the second one stand?? Why is the product a subset of the intersection?? 

$$(I_1 + \dots +I_m) \trianglelefteq R \\ (I_1 \cdot \dots \cdot I_m) \trianglelefteq R$$ means that $(I_1 + \dots +I_m)$ and $(I_1 \cdot \dots \cdot I_m)$ are ideals of $R$.

Comment: To simplify let's look at an ideal $I$. For any $a\in I$ and $r\in R$, $ra\in I$. Now consider a second ideal $J$. If $b\in J$, $ab\in I$ by the property given above. On the other hand, since $b\in J$, $ab\in J$ by the same property.

Comment: Can we say it as followed?? Let $a \cdot b \in I_1 \cdot I_2$, then $a \in I_1$ and $b \in I_2$. Since $I_1, I_2$ are ideals $a \cdot b \in I_1, a \cdot b \in I_2$. Then to show it for $m$ ideals do we use induction?? At the definition $$I_1 \cdot I_2 \cdot \dots \cdot I_m  =\{\text{ finite sum of products } a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot \dots \cdot a_m \mid a_i \in I_i\}$$ why is it a set of finite sum of products??

Comment: Be careful, $ab\in I_1\cdot I_2$ does not necessarily imply $a\in I_1$ and $b\in I_2$. Start with $a\in I_1$ and $b\in I_2$.  As for wny a set of finite sums of products, if we just included the products, there's no guarantee that product of ideals is closed under addition.

Comment: If $a \in I_1$ and $b \in I_2$ then $a \cdot b \in I_1 \cdot I_2$ ?? Since $I_1$ and $I_2$ are ideals, $a \cdot b \in I_1$ and $a \cdot b \in I_2$. Is this correct?? Could you explain to me further why it is a set of finite sums of products?? Why would there be no guarantee that the product of ideals is closed under addition??

Comment: Looks like you've got the idea as regards your first question. For the other, considered $a,c\in I_1$ and $b,d\in I_2$. So, $ab,cd\in I_1\cdot I_2$, but this doesn't necessarily mean $ab+cd\in I_1\cdot I_2$, unless we include the finite sums of products.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!!! :-)